# Should MVC OutputCache be used on non-controller methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-5, outputcache

I like the simplicity and usability that OutputCache offers in MVC Controllers. 
I could see a usage for such caching functionality in other "heavy" functions that are not controller actions, but since it is in the System.Web.Mvc namespace I was curios to know weather or not it is intended for that kind of use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not intended nor will it work for caching the output of a method.  Looking at the source code of the `OutputCache` attribute, it looks like it's very tightly coupled to the `HttpContext` and actually writes out to the response.  So it's really meant for caching the HTML output of your actions.